# Create Desktop shortcut

Tags: java, desktop-application

I am working on a java application.

I want to create desktop shortcut of my application's Exe file.

Is is possible to do it from my application itself ? Or user has to do it manually by right clicking ?

Answer (score 11):

```
package farzi;

import net.jimmc.jshortcut.JShellLink;

public class Sc {
    JShellLink link;
    String filePath;

    public Sc() {
        try {
            link = new JShellLink();
            filePath = JShellLink.getDirectory("")
                + "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe";

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    public void createDesktopShortcut() {

        try {
            link.setFolder(JShellLink.getDirectory("desktop"));
            link.setName("ie");
            link.setPath(filePath);
            link.save();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        Sc sc = new Sc();
        sc.createDesktopShortcut();
    }
}
```

you can get the jar from [here](https://github.com/jimmc/jshortcut)

Comment: No idea why you are not upvoted. This seems to be the only way to create shortcuts with java from code.

Comment: @Markus : i would have loved a counter of how many people has it helped , would mean a lot more than upvote here :)

Answer (score 1):

Java Web Start does this.  You write a regular application with a regular main method, and point to it with a short XML file with a .jnlp extension.  When the user clicks the link to the XML file, Java Web Start will, among other things, create the shortcut, if your XML file contains this:

```
<information>
    <!-- Other elements go here -->
    <shortcut>
        <desktop/>
    </shortcut>
</information>
```

More details are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly old topic, nevertheless I came across Austin`s brilliant answer and encountered some problems using jshortcut from within NetBeans, but I fear this might also affect Ecclipse.

1. Adding jshortcut.dll to java.library.path from wihtin NetBeans using properties->Run->VM options did not work.
2. Adding this dll by source code like "*System.setProperty("java.library.path", yourDllPath)"* does not work either.
3. Instead put jshortcut.dll to that particular folder where you store your jar`s for this project. JShellLink looks at this folder on its own, so you don`t need to add the DLL`s path to any path, which could cause trouble when running on some closed-down machines.
4. Most Important: When downloading your jshortcut.dll- Version, use AMD for all actual Intel machines. Rename the dll to shortcut.dll after downloading. JShellLink only looks for shortcut.dll, it ignores all other names.

Excert form jShellLink:
/** Provide access to shortcuts (shell links) from Java.
 *
 * The native library (jshortcut.dll) is loaded when JShellLink is first
 * loaded.
 * By default, JShellLink first looks for the native library in the PATH,
 * using System.loadLibrary.
 * If the native library is not found in the PATH,
 * JShellLink then looks through each directory in the CLASSPATH
 * (as determined by the value of the system property java.class.path).
 * If an entry in the CLASSPATH is a jar file,
 * then JShellLink looks for the native library
 * in the directory containing that jar file.
 * The application can override this behavior and force JShellLink to look
 * for the native library in a specific directory by setting the system
 * property JSHORTCUT_HOME to point to that directory.
 * This property must be set before the JShellLink class is loaded.
 * This makes it possible to use this library from a self-extracting jar file.
 */